# Script solution for tabs in bash wanted

Tags: linux, bash, putty

i'm in search for a solution for the following situation:
I am working for a customer who only allows accessing the linux servers
by putty (from a Windows Terminal Server).
Unfortunately i need multiple Session to work properly and effective.
Tmux and Screen are not a good option for me, because i need a visual
"tab" to keep track of all the stuff im doing.
Is this even possible or am i lost here?

Best regards.

Comment: Perfectly possible in screen: [Tabs when using screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26248/tabs-when-using-screen) -- [How to open tabs windows in GNU screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one)

Comment: The .screenrc looks nice but doesn't deliver my needs of seeing all tabs at the same time. You have other suggestions? :)

Comment: Do you need *tabs*, i.e. small handles that remind you what other terminals you still have open, or are you asking about having multiple *windows* side-by-side?

Comment: Anyway... how familiar / comfortable are you with Vim? Because there is ConqueTerm, a Vim plug-in that allows you to start a bash (or whatever) *using a Vim buffer for I/O*. Since you can have Vim buffers arranged in tabs *and* windows, that might be an option for you (although it is a bit tricky combining working in a shell with Vim commands... ;-) )

Comment: I want something like the tabs in Chrome or Gnome-Terminal that are allways visible and show something like a string or id. Than it would be enought to do something like "reconnect stresstest" where "reconnect" is some bash function for connecting to a tab and "stresstest" is the name of a tab.

Comment: I'm not able to install anything more on the linux servers or the windows terminal server :S

Comment: I am *completely* unclear about how you picture that "reconnect" thing to work. A tab would represent an open connection / shell. What would you want "reconnect"? -- Have a closer look at the two screen answers I linked. They do *exactly* the same as a Chrome or Gnome-Terminal tab, and are customizable.

Comment: Sir, you are a genius and i cannot read correctly. Saved my next half year!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Perfectly possible in screen: [How to open tabs windows in GNU screen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74785/how-to-open-tabs-windows-in-gnu-screen-execute-commands-within-each-one) – DevSolar

Perfectly solved my problem! Thanks DevSolar!

Comment: Happy to serve. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

MremoteNG does tabs and uses Putty (Putty comes with it). If you have RDP or console access to Windows server, you can upload MremoteNG portable.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using PuTTY, you can simply open two sessions at once. Open your first session, then right-click on the PuTTY icon in your taskbar, click "PuTTY" from the context menu, and it'll open a new instance of the program. Unfortunately, this won't result in a second tab, but instead it will result in a second *window* and you can swap back and forth between windows.

Other SSH clients *do* have actual tabs as a feature - one example is [MobaXTerm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/), which is free and doesn't require admin privileges to use on your computer, and which is indeed tabbed. It can also import your existing PuTTY configurations, so setting it up is pretty quick.

Comment: Yes, i know that. The problem with multiple open putty session is, that i need to enter my credentials every time again (RSA-token). This is the reason i thought there might be another solution...

Comment: And i forgot to mention, that i am not allowed to install other software :(

Answer (score -1):

You can get this application that allows you to have mulptiple tabs in putty. you dont need to "install" it so your lack of permissions wont be an issue :

http://ttyplus.com/multi-tabbed-putty/

Regarding your auth issue, I would recommend read this :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Note - Dont worry about being lost, everybody learns at different speeds.

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but i'm not able to use SSH-Keys, otherwise i would already have :). I hava a RSA token that changes it's code every 30 seconds or so. And i'm also not able to use any other software because i can neither download nor copy files to the Windows Terminal Server. It's a super closed environment :S

Comment: oh what a shame.I dont have any other solution for such a closed environment. :(